# JSON Exception occuring for multiple projects

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am currently working on an app and I am trying to implement a user system with login/registatration. I've been going over several tutorials to get an idea what to do. Now I am beginng to wonder if something is wrong with my eclipse enviroment because after trying 2 or 3 tutorials (and downloading the source code to test), I keep getting the same errors.

Rather than posting all the code (there is a lot)...Here is a link to the projects tutorial
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html

[I also tried this tutorial and had the same errors.](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/)

Here are the errors I'm getting. Could someone offer some ideas on what I should try looking at. I uploaded the code on my domain `IE http://mydomain.com/apifolder/, and tested this locally http://192.168.0.6/apifolder/`. If I need to post anything else let me know.

```
03-06 08:15:23.120: E/ViewRootImpl(32166): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-06 08:15:23.405: E/JSON(32166): Table 'usertest.users' doesn't exist
03-06 08:15:23.405: E/JSON Parser(32166): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-06 08:15:23.405: D/AndroidRuntime(32166): Shutting down VM
03-06 08:15:23.405: W/dalvikvm(32166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4195e700)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at com.learn2crack.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:212)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at com.learn2crack.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-06 08:15:23.410: E/AndroidRuntime(32166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


package com.learn2crack;

/**
 * Author :Raj Amal
 * Email  :raj.amalw@learn2crack.com
 * Website:www.learn2crack.com
 **/

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.learn2crack.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.learn2crack.library.UserFunctions;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.register);

    /**
     * Defining all layout items
     **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                    NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
       }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }





    private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

/**
 * Defining Process dialog
 **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
               fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
               lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
                email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
                password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       /**
        * Checks for success message.
        **/
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                        String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            /**
                             * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                             **/

                            UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                            logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                            /**
                             * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                             * Launch Registered screen
                             **/

                            Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                            /**
                             * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                            **/
                            registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(registered);


                              finish();
                        }

                        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                        }
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                        }

                    }


                        else{
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }}
        public void NetAsync(View view){
            new NetCheck().execute();
        }}





package com.learn2crack;

/**
 * Author :Raj Amal
 * Email  :raj.amalw@learn2crack.com
 * Website:www.learn2crack.com
 **/

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.learn2crack.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.learn2crack.library.UserFunctions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Login extends Activity {

    Button btnLogin;
    Button Btnregister;
    Button passreset;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        Btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        passreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passres);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);

        passreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PasswordReset.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
        }});


        Btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Register.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
             }});

/**
 * Login button click event
 * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
 **/
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    NetAsync(view);
                }
                else if ( ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
 **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
        **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
     **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
               if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                       /**
                        *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                        **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
                    }else{

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

The issues apperently were all related to the connection failing. I figured out where the errors were, specifically the database wasn't correctly set up, it was working. Is there a way to catch this without creating a null exception? I'd like the app to not crash if the database isn't available for some reason.

Comment: post `Login.java` and indicate line 212.

Comment: @Raghunandan Line `212` of that script is, `Register.java`.

Comment: what is the whole line-of-code at 212 ?

Comment: It looks like it may be a connection issue. I'll post if I see some change but I think I may have found the issue

Comment: Okay..Its working. When testing this locally. What IP do I use? The address of the computer running the webserver? Or something else?

Comment: As null pointer exception is throwing by your ProcessLogin asynctask onPostExecute line 212, here your getting some null object, if you can share this class, will find out the problem.